# How to display <<data...>> in AppleScript display dialog command?

Tags: binary, applescript

I retrieve the binary content of an image file like:
«data JPEGFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFDB00430006040506050406060506070706080A100A0A09090A140E0F0C1017141818171416161A1D251F1A1B231C1616202C20232627292A29191F2D302D283025282928FFDB0043010707070A080A130A0A13281A161A28282828282828282828282828282828282828>>
and I want to display these data via "display dialog" command. But I get error like "Can't make <> to string". So is there any way to display these data using display dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
set xxx to «data JPEGFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFDB00430006040506050406060506070706080A100A0A09090A140E0F0C1017141818171416161A1D251F1A1B231C1616202C20232627292A29191F2D302D283025282928FFDB0043010707070A080A130A0A13281A161A28282828282828282828282828282828282828»
try
    set xxx to xxx as text
on error errMsg
    set errMsg to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of errMsg & " | grep -o «.*»"
    display dialog errMsg
end try
```